# White border around images only when linked to href?

Tags: html, css

I’ve been puzzling over this for a while. I’d like to have row of 4 images which are links to other pages. The images next to each other form a block of colour and therefore I don’t want and space between them.

I have been able to get the images to work perfectly by using a class in CSS to remove the border, padding and margin or just with html on each image.

As soon as I add the href to create the link, a white border appears around the image and obscurs the adjacent images. I can’t remove the border in either html or CSS whenever the href is added. Where am I going wrong?

EDIT

Thanks for suggestions - but still no luck. I have the following:

HTML

```
<a href="LINK"><img class="testpage" src="IMAGE.jpeg" /></a><a href="LINK"><img class="testpage" src="IMAGE.jpeg" /></a><a href="LINK"><img class="testpage" src="IMAGE.jpeg" /></a>
```

CSS

```
.testpage {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}


img, a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [How do I remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/4642212), [Image inside div has extra space below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5804256/4642212).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image inside div has extra space below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help - as it turned out, I had the HTML and CSS correct, but was overridden by the theme CSS below.

```
/* Fixes linked images */
    .entry-content a img,
    .comment-content a img,
    .widget a img {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px #fff;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px #fff;
}
```

I changed the 8px to 0px and now it allows me to set the spacing.

Not sure why this section of code is necessary though!

Answer (score -2):

Hope this helps. The issue is not with the anchor.

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
<a href="LINK"><img class="testpage" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" /></a>
<a href="LINK"><img class="testpage" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" /></a>
<a href="LINK"><img class="testpage" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: It’s very unlikely that this fixes it. This CSS doesn’t remove the descender gap below the image. It also doesn’t remove spacing between images.

Comment: thanks for the update, but still showing gaps between. it's like the later images overlap the previous ones. I'm try to add screen grab above